# Dynamically add properties to a class

Tags: java, c#

I would like to be able to dynamically set properties to an existing class (object), during the runtime.

For example, having the interface `MyProperty.java`, and other specific properties implementing that interface. Then having an object that can dynamically receive some instance of `MyProperty` and automatically have a **getter** for it.

**MyPropery.java** [interface representing some Object property]

```
public interface MyProperty {
    String getValue();
}
```

**MyPropertyAge.java** [some specific Object property]

```
public class MyPropertyAge implements MyProperty {

    private final String age;

    public MyPropertyAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

**MyObject.java** [Object that should have a getter for MyProperty dynamically]

```
public class MyObject {

    public MyObject(Set<MyProperty> properties) {
        // receive list of properties,
        // and have getters for them
    }

    // For example, if I passed in a Set with 1 instance of "MyPropertyAge", I want to have this

    public MyPropertyAge getMyPropertyAge() {
        // implementation
    }
```

}

So the thing is to have properties added to a class **dynamically**, based on the set of properties it receives in a constructor. Something similar to `dynamic` keyword in C#: [Dynamically add properties to a existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329489/dynamically-add-properties-to-a-existing-object)

Is such thing possible in Java, or some hack that would do the same?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832554/how-to-add-attributes-dynamically-for-java-object) Q/A, I think this is what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as the `dynamic` keyword in Java.

However, you could use an internal `Map` to store properties. For example:

**MyObject.java**

```
public class MyObject {
    private HashMap<String, Object> properties;

    //Create object with properties
    public MyObject(HashMap<String, Object> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    //Set properties
    public Object setProperty(String key, Object value) {
        return this.properties.put(key, value); //Returns old value if existing
    }

    //Get properties
    public Object getProperty(String key) {
        return this.properties.getOrDefault(key, null);
    }
}
```

**Example: Person**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Create properties
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    //Add name and age
    properties.put("name", "John Doe");
    properties.put("age", 25);

    //Create person
    MyObject person = new MyObject(properties);

    //Get properties
    System.out.println(person.getProperty("age")); //Result: 25
    System.out.println(person.getProperty("name")); //Result: John Doe
}
```

There exist various ways to implement this, but this is probably the most simple way to do it.