# wrapper to provide unified method parameters

Tags: java

In Python, I can do something like this:

```
class Demo:
    def x(self, prefix, x, y):
        print("Demo.x, prefix=%s, x=%s, y=%s" % (prefix, x, y))
        return 3

    def y(self, prefix, i):
        print("Demo.y, prefix=%s, i=%d" % (prefix, i))

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, inst, prefix):
        self.inst = inst
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print("function %s is called" % name)
        func = getattr(self.inst, name)
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: func(self.prefix, *args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inst = Demo()
    wrapper = Wrapper(inst, "prefix")
    print(wrapper.x("a", "b")) 
    wrapper.y(123)
```

in this code I can use wrapper to provide a unified prefix, without re-define all methods of class Demo in class Wrapper.

I just want to know how to implement the same thing in Java?

I looked Dynamic Proxy, but it seems cannot change the arguments.

this is what I tried:

```
public class Wrapper {

  private Class cls;
  private final Object inst;
  private final String header;

  public Wrapper(Class cls, Object inst, String header){
    System.out.println("C=" + cls.getName());
    this.cls = cls;
    this.inst = inst;
    this.header = header;
  }

  public Object invoke(String funcName, Object ...args)
      throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

    for (Method method : this.cls.getMethods()) {
      if (method.getName().equals(funcName)) {
        ArrayList argList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(args));
        argList.add(0, header);
        return method.invoke(this.inst, argList.toArray());
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

which can used as this:

```
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(DemoService.class, service, "prefix");
return (String)wrapper.invoke("test", "this is a test");
```

However, "invoke" method is not so intuitive and convenient.

Comment: You want to set Class's member and get the same ?

Comment: Could you show what you tried so far ?

Comment: So you're trying to curry an arbitrary collection of methods?

Comment: @MickaëlB I added some info now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add attributes Dynamically for java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832554/how-to-add-attributes-dynamically-for-java-object)

Comment: @KevinWallis Not at all, this is currying functions.

Comment: what is your exact problem, do you really need a wrapper? because this code does not have very good performance. can you use e.g. any kind of decorator or interface?

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement the wrapper functionality you desire would be to use a combination of generics and functional interfaces of Java 8:

```
public class Wrapper<P1> {
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface TriFunction<P1, P2, P3, R> {
        R apply(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3);
    }

    private P1 value;

    public Wrapper(P1 value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <R> R invoke(Function<P1, R> func) {
        return func.apply(value);
    }

    public <R, P2> R invoke(BiFunction<P1, P2, R> func, P2 value2) {
        return func.apply(value, value2);
    }

    public <R, P2, P3> R invoke(TriFunction<P1, P2, P3, R> func, P2 value2, P3 value3) {
        return func.apply(value, value2, value3);
    }
}
```

You can use this wrapper with method references (:: operator) like this:

```
public class A {
    public String identity(String value) {
        return value;
    }

    public String concat(String value1, String value2) {
        return value1 + value2;
    }

    public String concat(String value, int val) {
        return value + val;
    }

    public String concat(String value1, String value2, int val) {
        return value1 + value2 + val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper<String> wrapper = new Wrapper<>("toto");
        A a = new A();
        wrapper.invoke(a::identity);           // returns "toto"
        wrapper.invoke(a::concat, "tutu");     // returns "tototutu"
        wrapper.invoke(a::concat, 10);         // returns "toto10"
        wrapper.invoke(a::concat, "tutu", 10); // returns "tototutu10"
    }
}
```

This solution introduces boxing with simple types so you may want to offer an `invoke` method which accepts `IntFunction`, `ObjIntFunction` and the like. It also only handles calling methods with up to 3 parameters but I think the pattern to handle more is easy to figure out.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?