# Copy object structure and values

Tags: java

Suppose, I have a class like this...

```
public class MyClass {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() // .... 
    // ... usual getters 
}
```

And I want to dynamically make a new object and has the exact same fields and values and add just three more? How do I do that.  One idea convert MyClass to a Map and just add the fields.

Any better idea?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _dynamically_?

Comment: There's aren't many "good" ways to do this in Java.  You can create a "copy constructor" that takes an object of `MyClass` and copies all of its fields.  You can use reflection to copy all fields.  You can use `clone()`, but that is deprecated.  You can serialize and deserialize objects, but that exposes a `Serializable` interface.

Comment: I wouldn't try to create a class dynamically.  Because Java is a statically typed language, you would only be able to access it as an `Object`, and you would need to use reflection to access the values.  Have you considered simply creating a Map?  Since this is just a POJO and there's no behavior, this is the approach I would take.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832554/how-to-add-attributes-dynamically-for-java-object) helps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java